# Download Crunchbase profile images using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate downloading company profile images from Crunchbase's OpenDataMap using R. I've tried download.file, GET (in httr package) and getURLContent in RCurl, but they all return a 416 error. I know that I must be forgetting a parameter or user_agent, but I can't figure out what.

Here's an example URL for testing:

http://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google-ventures/primary-image/raw

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Can't you use their API? https://developer.crunchbase.com/ A brief snoop round the URL you gave leads me into a world of obfuscated javascript and "suspicious activity detected" web pages. My conclusion: they don't like scraping. Use the API.

Comment: There's even an R package for it: https://github.com/tarakc02/rcrunchbase

Comment: Their API returns a organization's profile image url, unless I'm mistaken. Not exactly helpful.

Comment: It is helpful, since if you want to put the image into HTML you can do `<img src="http://www.crunchbase.com/organization/google-ventures/primary-image/raw">` and the image redirect magic all seems to work. Which makes me wonder if JS is not involved, because running JS from an image tag gives me the fear. But as you say, I've tried via `curl` with all the params from the request and no joy...

Comment: Might have to just download them using a browser hack. I hate doing stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I came up with a fairly clever, albeit slow-ish solution that worked with R.

Essentially, I created a headless browser that navigates from page-to-page, downloading the crunchbase images I need. This allows me to get past the 'redirect' and javascript that stops me from getting to the images via a simple Curl request.

This may work for other scraping projects.

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()
# For each url of interest profile_image_url is a list of image urls from crunchbase's open data map.
for(row in 1:length(profile_image_url)){
  print(row) # keep track of where I am
  # if already downloaded, don't do it again
  if(file.exists(paste0("profileimages/",row,".png"))| file.exists(paste0("profileimages/",row,".jpg"))|file.exists(paste0("profileimages/",row,".gif"))){
    next
  }
  # navigate to new page
  remDr$navigate(paste0(profile_image_url[row],"?w=500&h=500"))
  imageurl <- remDr$getCurrentUrl()[[1]]
  # get file extension (to handle pngs and jpgs
  file.ext <- gsub('[^\\]*\\.(\\w+)$',"\\1", imageurl)
  # download image file from 'real' url
  download.file(imageurl, paste0("profileimages/",thiscid,".",file.ext), method="curl")
  # wait ten seconds to avoid rate-limiting
  Sys.sleep(10)
}
remDr$close()
```

Comment: After using this for several hours, it appears that crunchbase also has a daily limit on page access/downloads. Might also need to limit in that area or switch ip addresses.